# What are the limitations of active noise cancelling?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, sound-isolation

Let´s pretend there is a source of homogenous noise. Up to which decibel level could active noise cancelling be viable to decrease the volume of this noise significantly? Is it like 10, 50, 100 dB?

Comment: “Significantly” needs to be quantified. Would a 50% reduction in volume be significant? What about measured vs perceived volume? This could descend into psychoacoustics... As far as I’m aware, there is no theoretical limitation - given two perfectly opposed waveforms, they will cancel out. The practical limitations (delay due to processing time, imperfect recreation of the opposing sound due to hardware limitations) are much more relevant.